# or condition seems to fail in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I have a very long list like this:

`old_list = ['cat','dog','bat','cat',...]`

I am using the following code to copy this entire list into another with changes for some specific conditions:

```
new_list = []
for item in old_list:
    if item == ("cat" or "bat"):
        new_list.append("a")
    elif item == "dog" or "fog" or "sog" or "log":
        new_list.append("o")
    else:
        new_list.append(item)
```

The problem is that in some cases "cat" and "bat" are correctly replaced by "a" but in some cases "cat" or "bat" remains as it is when I print `new_list`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not comparing item against "fog", "sog" or "log" - you're actually checking if the value as a boolean returns True or False

Comment: @AK47 so how do i compare?

Comment: You don't have an if before your first elif. And use `if item in ["cat", "bat"]`

Comment: So close to submitting an answer before this got closed. oh well. You also should change your first `elif` to and `if`. an add an `item ==` after every `or`

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?  Can you elaborate more in your question?  Right now, it would print things like `["a", "o", "other word"]`

Comment: How many times have I seen this dupe...

Comment: Add your brackets around dog, fog, sog and log like you did in line 3

Comment: @MatthewCiaramitaro thanks. i made the mistake while typing here.

Comment: Actually, `item == ("cat" or "bat")` seems to be a new variant of the theme, that's evaluated as `item == "cat"` (as `("cat" or "bat")` evaluates as `"cat"`).

Comment: @Igle  thanks. i made the mistake while typing here.

Comment: you could also do `if item in ["cat,"bat","dog",...]: new_list.append(item[1])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
if item in {"dog", "fog", "sog", "log"}:
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

This will solve your isse

```
old_list = ['cat','dog','bat','cat']
new_list = []
for item in old_list:
    if item == "cat" or item=="bat":
        new_list.append("a")
    elif item == "dog" or item== "fog" or item=="sog" or item=="log":
        new_list.append("o")
    else:
        new_list.append(item)
print(new_list)
```